# How do I avoid error ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Cannot provide both 'Poll' and 'QuestionAndAnswers' capability values at the same time

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed, connect-api, chatter-groups

I am trying to set a question title for a poll chatter post created by apex using the following code

```
CollaborationGroup g = [SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name='Edge Communications Customer Support'];
ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput poll = new ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput();
poll.choices = 'Yes,No'.split(',');
    ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput feedElementCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
    ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswersCapabilityInput questionAndAnswersCapabilityInput = new ConnectApi.QuestionAndAnswersCapabilityInput();
    ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
    feedElementCapabilitiesInput.poll = poll;
    feedElementCapabilitiesInput.questionAndAnswers = questionAndAnswersCapabilityInput;
    questionAndAnswersCapabilityInput.questionTitle = 'Are we doing a good job handling Edge Communications customer support inquiries?';

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
 feedItemInput.capabilities = feedElementCapabilitiesInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = g.Id;
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, feedItemInput );
```

When I execute this code, I receive the following error

```
 !    ERROR: ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Cannot provide both 'Poll' and
 !    'QuestionAndAnswers' capability values at the same time.
 !    ERROR: Class.ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement: line 1458, column 1
 !    AnonymousBlock: line 27, column 1
ERROR running force:apex:execute:  Class.ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement: line 1458, column 1
AnonymousBlock: line 27, column 1
```

Looks like it doesn't want me to provide both choices and question title at the same time. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

The question title should be set through textSegment :

```
CollaborationGroup g = [SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name='Edge Communications Customer Support'];
User a = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE CommunityNickname = 'ahartzler'];
User f = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE CommunityNickname = 'fsuzuki'];
ConnectApi.ChatterGroups.addMember(null, g.Id, a.Id);
ConnectApi.ChatterGroups.addMember(null, g.Id, f.Id);

ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, g.Id, ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, 'Welcome to the Edge Communications Customer Support group. We will use this space to share efficiency and workflow improvement ideas for Edge Communications customer support cases.');

ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput poll = new ConnectApi.PollCapabilityInput();
poll.choices = 'Yes,No'.split(',');
    ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput feedElementCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
    ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
    feedElementCapabilitiesInput.poll = poll;


ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.capabilities = feedElementCapabilitiesInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;

feedItemInput.subjectId = g.Id;
messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = 'Are we doing a good job handling Edge Communications customer support inquiries?';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, feedItemInput );
```